# unity mouse rotation lag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I am making a game in unity and the rotation of my character moves to some random location whenever I have a lag spike. I have no clue what could be causing it and I could not find anything else on the internet on this. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Range(1f,1000f)]
    public float mouseSensitivity;

    public Transform playerBody;

    private float xRoatation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        xRoatation = 0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRoatation -= mouseY;
        xRoatation = Mathf.Clamp(xRoatation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRoatation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        
    }
}
```

Here is a video link of the problem in action:
https://medal.tv/games/horror-waiwai/clips/1toWBrpQGTahtl/d1337ixaUaC0?invite=cr-MSxrZHcsMTk5MzQ1MzI4LA

I tried changing the update method to fixed update and nothing happened